# Executing the printed statement

Tags: python

I have a print statement in python script.

```
print "mysql -e\"insert into test.syllabalize values (",text_index, ",", index, ",", "'",syllable,"')\""
```

This output the correct mysql statement...

```
mysql -e"insert into test.syllabalize values ( 3 , 5 , 'abc')"
```

How do I execute this statement?

It only prints it to the standard out.

Update:

The following will try to insert the text instead of the values of the variables.

```
os.system('mysql -e"insert into test.syllabalize values (\'text_index\', \'index\', \'syllable\')"')
```

How do I replace the values with variables in the above statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("mysql -e\"insert into test.syllabalize values (",text_index, ",", index, ",", "'",syllable,"')\"",shell=True)
p.wait()
```

but you should look at using one of python modules for mysql database access rather than doing this. those let you use:

```
db.execute("insert into test.syllabalize values (?,?,?)", (text_index, index, syllable))
```

parameterized queries provide complete protection from sql injection

in fact subprocess.Popen provides them too

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["mysql", "-e", "\"insert into test.syllabalize values (",text_index, ",", index, ",", "'",syllable,"')\""])
```

no shell injection is possible in this form but the sql query is still vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using MySQL, why not use MySQLdb, it's much more secure and easier.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("host", "user", "pass", "db")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("insert into test.syllabalize values ( %s , %s , %s)", (3,5,"abc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using the `system` built-in function. For much more advanced control use the `subprocess` module of the standard library.

P.S. To avoid security issues, make sure you sanitize SQL queries and beware of input received from the user.

Comment: os.system is not to be used, all commands should be done via the subprocess module

Comment: os.system is what I was looking for. But it is inserting the variable name instead of variable values in the DB. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. But here's a try.

```
test_index = 3
index = 5
syllable = 'abc'

os.system('mysql -e"insert into test.syllabalize values ({0}, {1}, {2})"' % (test_index, index, syllable))
```

Comment: # Python 2.4.3 # AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Yes, Python 2.4.3 doesn't include format. It was added in 2.6. For 2.4.3 you want:


os.system('mysql -e"insert into test.syllabalize values (%s, %s, %s)"' % (test_index, index, syllable))